# How to download/unzip a long list of files and process each file in Java

Tags: java, bash

I want to perform static analysis on the java files from a long list of java GitHub repositorys (1000+ plus). I have a list of URLs that are download links for the zipped repo. I have the links stored in CSV and also within a MongoDB collection.

I have a java program that can perform the text analysis on each repo, however, I am struggling with how to automate this process, primarily how to DL the repos from the URLs.

The total process :

- iterate through a list of URLS for each link.
- Download the content.
- Process the content ( in my program ).
- Delete the folder.
- move to the next Link.

I am struggling with how to correctly automate this process.

I have tried use bash from inside my java program which did work, I was able to DL the repo and unzip it but I quickly run into some sort of timing error, after the second successful downloaded link it halted and when I manually stopped the process a third DL appeared in the chosen directory, suggesting some sort of timing error.

Alternatively, I have tried to collect the files I need outside of the java program and then pipe the results in ( however I only programmed something similar with C++). I thought to run a bash script to DL the repo, cat the java files into a text file and pipes that result in my java program, however, then I am not sure how to iterate the URL links in the first place.

Am I approaching this task in the wrong way?

Comment: Doesn't the java standard library have a class to handle zip files? Especially since that's what jar files are...

Comment: @Shawn [It does indeed.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

Comment: Assuming your static analysis program can accept an InputStream or Reader, there is no need to download files.  You can wrap the URLConnection’s InputStream in a [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and read each file directly from there.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely make a decision as to whether your Java analysis program will be self-contained or not (whether it will download the repositories and analyse them, or only analyse them).

If it should be self-contained, do not use Bash at all. Stick to Java. Use external libraries if that facilitates your job.

If it won't be self-contained, use `wget`, `curl` or `git` to retrieve the files. This seems to me like the easiest approach. You'll probably want to download the tarballs rather than the full Git repository. Git keeps the entire history, so 5 megs of files could have 1 gig of history, since downloading the tarballs (a snapshot of the current repository) will be faster and less bandwidth-intensive. Just add `/archive/master.zip` to every repository's URL.

You'll want something like this

```
for url in $URLS; do
  curl -LO $url
  unzip master.zip
  java AnalyzeCode .
  rm *
done
```